# Can anyone recommend me a good travel book about the area Black Forest in Germany?

Tags: germany, guidebooks

I am going on a holiday the south of Germany for one week. And I am looking for a good book about Black Forest (in English). I like hiking and castles. So, this book should provide me with such information. Of course, I hope it is colorful. If you know any good one, please tell me.

Comment: Recommendation questions are not really what Stack Exchange is designed for because they don't have "one right answer". At least [one previous one very similar to yours](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1245/what-is-a-good-las-vegas-guide-book) was closed as "off topic".

Comment: I voted to reopen. In the mean time we have a lot of recommendations question. This particular one is asking for a book while others are asking about itineraries. But basically, it is the same.

Comment: Let's see what people'll say.